# iOS app being killed while in the background?

Tags: ios, geolocation, core-location, background-process

I created an app that tracks user location even while in the background. The app will then record the users gps coords to core data and send to them to an app when the user chooses to end the session. This seemed to be working ok while developing but now I'm getting reports that the app is missing large chucks of gps points.

I added some logging to the app (via the loge tries.com api) and it appears that sometimes when the app enters the background music it stops logging then later I can see a message  that the app delegate's didfinishlaunching is invoked again. This makes me think that the app is being killed? Are there any solid examples on how this should be coded to continually run in the background? The functionality that I need is very similar to a navigation app where the location is constantly monitored while it's active.

I tried to save some battery life by turning off the gps after a minute or so then firing it backup every 5 minutes since that's the frequency that I need.

It's based on this code: http://mobileoop.com/background-location-update-programming-for-ios-7

I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this should work at this point and I haven't come across any example on the apple developer center that speak to this.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using significant location change in background ?
In my opinion, this is the correct way to go.

Here is what is happening if you're using it :

1. Your app is in foreground and get location
2. App goes in background and is waiting for significant location change.
   In this mode, you'll probably get less location calls. And only if you're moving.
3. App get suspended (automatic) or killed by the user
4. iOS get a significant location change, it'll call all app that were recording those and they'll be waken up in background.
5. get back to 3.

from [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) :

> The significant-change location service can also wake up an iOS app that is currently suspended or not running in order to deliver new location data.

This is why `didfinishlaunching` is invoked again